# How to pass part of URL to ProxyPass in Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy, reverse-proxy, httpd, httpd.conf

I am hitting the URL `http://example.com/ws/abc`. Now I need to proxy a server with URL `https://server.com/abc`.

I have tried the 2 methods below to proxy. But it is not working.

1. `RewriteRule ^/ws/(.*) "https://server.com/$1" [P]`
2. `ProxyPassMatch ^/ws/(.*)  https://server.com/$1`

What is the possible issue?
I can not seem to get just the `abc` from the URL. I get `/ws/abc`.

Comment: What exactly does "not working" mean, do you have any logs, error messages, other outputs, that could help us help you?

Comment: It also depends where is your configuration snippet located? In main Apache configuration or in an `.htaccess` file? If so, which one?